# Create index.php file in directory

Tags: c#, file, directory, command-line-arguments

I want to write a program to be added to the right-click menu and when I run the program from the right-click menu to create an `index.php` file in current directory!

**Exmaple:**

- I go to `C:\wamp\www`
- Then I right-click somewhere and want to choose `create index.php`
- This should create a new file called `index.php` in the directory I clicked

**Desired action:**

A new file called `index.php` wil be created at `C:\wamp\www\index.php`

**More Details:**

I want to make it look like "Text Document" in "New":

`right-click => new => text document`

when we click it windows create "New Text Document.txt" ... now i want when we click on my program windows create "index.php" file!

Registry path that this program will be operate within it:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\`

thanks to all ...

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: i don't know how to get current directory path at different times... at the first we will get path so create file!

Comment: You can copy and paste "get current directory path" into google and get lots of answers to your comment. What have you tried/researched? Your question is too broad.

Comment: no ... you don't understand my question correctly!

Comment: when i use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); that return c:\users\username\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Index.php\Index.php\bin\Debug ! but i don't want it ! i want the path that user click on "create index.php" option... for example ... user in F:/New Folder/ clicked on "create index.php" then program will be create index.php into F:/New Folder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace createIndex_php
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(args[0])) // right clicked on a file in explorer
                {
                    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    path = args[0];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Error while creating ""index.php"": {0}", ex.Message));
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            if (path != string.Empty)
            {
                path = Path.Combine(path, "index.php");
                try
                {
                    File.Create(path);
                    Console.WriteLine(@"""index.php"" created!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Error while creating ""index.php"": {0}", ex.Message));
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will do the creation of the `index.php` file.

Anyway, you have to subscribe your app to the right click menu using `regedit` and go to following key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

Please see the following links for that:

- https://goo.gl/UV2L57
- https://superuser.com/a/392215/434088
- http://goo.gl/hrpKFw
- http://goo.gl/nC6hVp

Comment: i copy this code on console application project ... so from registry link it to an option on right-click menu ... but when i run it cmd show this error message: "Error while creating "index.php" : index was outside the bounds of the array." what to do?

Comment: have you had a look at the `superuser` link and followed all instructions??

Comment: please look at my question ... i have edited it now !

Comment: is anybody here to answer me?

Comment: @R3Z4BH this will not work (without very very deep os cracking and overriding), as explorer does not actually collect the items, they're saved in the executable. Another problem is, that explorer does override all the items in the registry, when opening the right-click menu subitem `new`... if my answer helps you anyway, please mark it as solved!!